# Python Intelligent rounding of numbers

Tags: python, list, numbers, rounding

I have some weird numbers such as `19 or 23.` These two will need to be separated into `5 lists`, such that the sum of the 5 lists will be 19. In other words, 3.8 in each list as 19/5 = 3.8. However the issue is that I can't have decimals, I want rounded numbers. Is there any way that it would round the numbers accordingly, placing 4, 4, 3, 4, 4 into the lists rather than 3.8 five times?

Even more, some aren't separated into 5 different numbers. Some might be something like 77/12, thus being separated into 12 diff. lists with either the number 6 or 7 in each, that ends up adding to 77.

Any idea how I could approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very imprecise. `19 or 23.` is not "a set of numbers". Do you mean a set containing 19 different integers? Can you post some code that demonstrates what input you have, and shows what you've tried. Then explain what you want.

Comment: @MarkByers the OP was posting in the chat before. so i understand what he is asking. answered.

Comment: @InbarRose: But the question should still be clear so that a) other people can answer b) so that we can vote on the answers and c) other people reading this in the future who have the same problem can get the best answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Wrote the question before checking for a response in chat. Will edit with updated details now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def split(number, length):
    div, mod = divmod(number, length)
    return [div+1]*mod + [div]*(length-mod)

>>> split(19, 5)
[4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
>>> split(23, 4)
[6, 6, 6, 5]
```

Original version:

```
def split(number, length):
    result = [number//length]*length
    for i in range(number%length):
        result[i] += 1
    return result
```

Comment: very elegant, i have never seen `[number//length]` before, can you explain this to me?

Comment: @InbarRose - `//` is the future proof notation for floor division.  On Python 2.x this is equivalent to `number/length`, but on Python 3.x `number/length` would result in a float.

Comment: i should really start embracing the future, been stuck in 2.6 forever :)

Comment: The alternative isn't equivalent, it's **much better**

Comment: @InbarRose - The other thing going on there is `[n]*m`, which creates a list of length `m` with `n` at every index.  Same result as `[n for i in range(m)]`.

Comment: Whats the difference between the original and the alternative? Or how is it better?

Comment: The original version requires a loop to add one to each element in the list up to `length-1` times, and the alternative version avoids this loop so it is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

here you go.

```
def roundto(number,items):
    start = [1 for i in xrange(items)]
    reached = False
    while not reached:
        for i in xrange(len(start)):
            start[i] += 1
            if sum(start) == number:
                return start

print roundto(19,5)
>>> 
[4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
```